# Showing selected daterange in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, common-table-expression, dynamic-sql, date-range

I have a reporting tool where I need to show the output in below format,

If I select Start Date Time as 2019-01-10 00:00:00 and End Date Time as 2019-05-20 00:00:00,

The output should be like below,

[image]

Below is the query I ave tried but I'm getting only start date range or end date range but I need to show complete months date range if we select multiple months in the filter

```
DECLARE @StartDate DateTIme
DECLARE @EndDate DateTime

SET @StartDate='2018-01-26 01:10:00'
SET @EndDate='2018-02-27 02:31:00'

;WITH GETMONTHPART(MonthNumber1,MonthNames1,StartDate,EndDate,StartDateMonth,EndDateMonth,DayRange)
AS
(

SELECT DATEPART(MM,@StartDate) MONTHNUMBER,DATENAME(MONTH,@StartDate) MONTH,@StartDate,@EndDate,CONVERT(VARCHAR(25),
DATEADD(dd,-(DAY(@StartDate)-1),@StartDate),101),
CONVERT(VARCHAR(25),DATEADD(dd,-(DAY(DATEADD(mm,1,@EndDate))),DATEADD(mm,1,@EndDate)),101),
CONVERT(VARCHAR(25),DATEADD(dd,-(DAY(@StartDate)-1),@StartDate),101)+' - '+CONVERT(VARCHAR(25),DATEADD(dd,-(DAY(DATEADD(mm,1,@StartDate))),DATEADD(mm,1,@StartDate)),101) [TotalDaysofMonth]
)
,

--SELECT * FROM GETMONTHPART

CALLSUMMARY (Monthnumber,Monthname,callednumbercount) AS
(
SELECT DATEPART(MM,ccd.startdatetime) MONTHNUMBER,
DATENAME(MONTH,ccd.startdatetime) MONTH,
COUNT(callednumber) FROM table ccd WHERE startdatetime>=@StartDate and startdatetime<@EndDate
GROUP BY DATEPART(MM,ccd.startdatetime),
DATENAME(MONTH,ccd.startdatetime)
)

Select MonthName,DayRange,callednumbercount from CALLSUMMARY, GETMONTHPART

ORDER BY Monthnumber,Monthname ASC
```

This is the output currently i'm getting where January month range coming to February as well because the DateRange conversion is doing only to @StartDateTime. If we modify this to @EndDateTime, both DateRange will be come at Feb.

Hope this clarifies my question.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the issue is with grouping in first CTE. You can try something like this:

```
DECLARE @StartDate DateTIme
DECLARE @EndDate DateTime

SET @StartDate='2018-01-26 01:10:00'
SET @EndDate='2018-05-27 02:31:00'

;with a as(
          select chatID
                 ,convert(date,c.datetmStart) dateChat 
          from factChat c 
          WHERE c.datetmStart >=@StartDate 
                and c.datetmStart < @EndDate
         )

  select CONVERT(VARCHAR(25),DATEADD(dd,-(DAY(dateChat)-1),dateChat),101) startDateMonth
        ,CONVERT(VARCHAR(25),DATEADD(dd,-(DAY(DATEADD(mm,1,dateChat))),DATEADD(mm,1,dateChat)),101) EndDateMonth
        ,CONVERT(VARCHAR(25),DATEADD(dd,-(DAY(dateChat)-1),dateChat),101)+' - '+CONVERT(VARCHAR(25),DATEADD(dd,-(DAY(DATEADD(mm,1,dateChat))),DATEADD(mm,1,dateChat)),101) [DayRange]
        ,month(dateChat) monthNr
        ,count(chatID) totalChats
  from a
  group by CONVERT(VARCHAR(25),DATEADD(dd,-(DAY(dateChat)-1),dateChat),101)
          ,CONVERT(VARCHAR(25),DATEADD(dd,-(DAY(DATEADD(mm,1,dateChat))),DATEADD(mm,1,dateChat)),101) 
          ,CONVERT(VARCHAR(25),DATEADD(dd,-(DAY(dateChat)-1),dateChat),101)+' - '+CONVERT(VARCHAR(25),DATEADD(dd,-(DAY(DATEADD(mm,1,dateChat))),DATEADD(mm,1,dateChat)),101) 
          ,month(dateChat)
  order by month(dateChat)
```

I've used my internal table factChat, but I think you will get the point.

After running the query, I'm getting following results:

[image]

Comment: Hi thanks for the query, but it is not complete to my requirement. It is showing data for selected date hour range of Start date time, selected date hour range of End Date time and full month data of BETWEEN months. But I need full month date of both start and end date ranges as well. Could you please me with that as well?